# Get name of javascript variable when prototyped

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to get the current name of the varable as they are prototyped: Have a look at this example:

```
var Entities = new Array();
var Original = function(version){
    this.name = /**GET NAME OF PARENT*/;
    this.version = version
    Entities.push(this);
};

var bob123 = new Original(25);
```

I want to store `bob123` into `this.name` from above object. Is this possible without passing it as an parameter?

Comment: That's completely impossible

Answer (score 0):

No.

First, because the object is constructed (and the function run) *before* it is assigned to the variable.

Second, because references in JavaScript are one-way. References to an object might be stored in multiple variables.

```
var bob123 = new Original(25);
alice.bob = bob123;
window.foo = bob123;
```